# Composite ID unmapped class problem

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I want to specify the class map for 1 of the elements in composite id:

```
CompositeId()
                .KeyReference(x => x.User, "user_id")
                .KeyProperty(x => x.Key, "user_key");
```

Like this one:

```
References(x => x.User, "user_id").Class<User>()
```

But I get error for unmapped class because I use interfaces. I also tried the code bellow but no luck yet:

```
CompositeId()
                .KeyReference(x => x.User, e =>
e.Name(""user_id").EntityName("User"))


                .KeyProperty(x => x.Key, "user_key");
References(x => x.User, "user_id").Class<User>()
```

Comment: what is the exception you got? Have you tried to specify `EntityName("User");` in UserMap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the answer:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fluent-nhibernate/AnJosrxqIo8